# Исключить удаление пробелов между некоторыми словами

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Есть отрывок кода

```
arrRows[i].replace(/\s/g, '');
```

который убирает все пробелы из текста. Можно ли как-то добавить некоторые слова в исключения? Чтобы например между словами "Москва Россия" пробелы не удалялись.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно, добавьте эти исключения в захватвающую подмаску и замените обратной ссылкой на эту подмаску:

```js
var s = "Москва Россия- 1 2 3";
console.log(s.replace(/(Москва Россия)|\s/g, "$1"));
// => Москва Россия-123
```

**Подробности**

- `(Москва Россия)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: `Москва Россия`
- `|` - или
- `\s` - любой пробельный символ.

В шаблоне замены `$1` подставляет текстовое значение, захваченное подмаской №1.